# Buttons comes adjacent instead of coming down when using twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

am using twitterbootstrap to design a form. 
i see that buttons comes adjacent to last input field instead coming below the last input field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sign in &middot; Twitter Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }

      .form-signin {
        max-width: 500px;
        padding: 19px 29px 29px;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
      }
      .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
      .form-signin .checkbox {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .form-signin input[type="text"],
      .form-signin input[type="password"] {
        font-size: 16px;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding: 7px 9px;
      }

    </style>
    <link href="../CP/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../CP/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../CP/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../CP/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../CP/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../CP/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../CP/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

<body style="background-color: #F5FBEF">



    <div class="container">
           <div class="row">

        <div class="span12" >
      <form class="form-signin">


        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register with Carpool</h2>

              <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Full Name">
              <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
              <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputMobile" placeholder="Mobile Number">
              <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputCarModel" placeholder="Car Model">
              <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputCarPlateNumber" placeholder="Car Plate No"/>
              <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='login.htm'">Register</button>
              <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Clear</button>

      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->



    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../CP/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="../CP/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

what should i do to get the buttons below last input field?

Best Regards
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Best is to wrap the the controls (and labels) in a `<fieldset>`. See the [TB documentation on  using forms](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).

Answer (score 0):

guys i found the solution.

what i did is that. i included the button elements in a separate DIV tag and it worked fine.
the buttons came below the input fields.

```
<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Full Name">
              <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
              <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputMobile" placeholder="Mobile Number">
              <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputCarModel" placeholder="Car Model">
              <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputCarPlateNumber" placeholder="Car Plate No"/>
              <div>
              <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='login.htm'">Register</button>
              <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Clear</button>
              </div>
```